# product old price in virtuemart

Tags: joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am using virtuemart for my application made by joomla 1.5 .
Now in my product list I am getting the old price and new price and also display how much I can save for that product.
But I am able to find out where these old and new price have been stored in database. Could you please guide me in which table that old price is stored?

Comment: which version of virtuemart are you using

Comment: I am using virtuemart 1.1.9

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correct then you want the base price and discount price(override).If yes then you can get the base price(old price) in the `jos_vm_product_price` table the column name is `product_price` and for the new price(override) is in the `jos_vm_product_discount` table and the column name is `amount`.See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help but could you please tell me how the product will be mapped in jos_vm_product_discount table. Obviously, I am getting 'amount' column but that amount is for which product, it confuses me.